# UIWebViewBounce phonegap

Tags: jquery, xcode, cordova

I'm trying to create an app with jquery mobile for the first time. 
I have searched the internet for solutions but nothing seems to work for my project
I can not find a way to get rid of the rubberanding on the top and bottom
 seems not solve this problem.
And because iscroll has quite some limitation and dont want to use that.

here is a photo that shows my problem
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6rini3swht160y4/Photo%201344.jpeg

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your config.xml

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
```

see here: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

Comment: no sorry nothing workes. i try everything. no single one solves it 
 <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
 <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false" />
 <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />

Comment: I guess you had a previous Version with .plist instead of config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

when UIWebview is loaded or created, insert following code.

```
// bouncing-lock for webView contents
for (id subview in webView.subviews)
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;
```

Comment: In general case, I recommend viewcontroller.m. :)